# Windows Shell Extension for Pictures Showing Geodata

Tags: windows-explorer, photos, gps, shell-extensions, geotagging

Does anyone know if a program exists that installs a shell extension for Windows that will display geodata from a photo?

I have a lot of photos taken with my iPhone that have GPS coordinates in the files (Flickr knows how to extract it). But I want to be able to see that information from within the Explorer shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Panorado Flyer](http://www.panorado.com/en/index.php?PanoradoFlyer.php) is a shell extension that enables you to rightclick on a jpg-image and show the location in Google Earth (extracted from the EXIF-information).

Comment: I've just had a play with this -- it's very cool.  In addition to flying to the location in Google Earth, you can also set the location by finding the correct place in Google Earth, then in Windows Explorer using the Panorado Flyer extension to get the location from Google Earth.  (Oh, and you can also just view and set the coordinates with a dialog if you don't want to use Google Earth.)  Best of all, it's free.

Comment: Yup! sweet. I did end up finding this myself later on after some intense sleuthing.